# export the function in node.js but having error TypeError: xxx is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have two files in node.js, one is hello.js and another file is going to call the function in the hello.js. I tried to export the function - hello_2018, but it comes with an error saying:

```
TypeError: hello.hello_2018 is not a function
```

Here is the code.

```
hello.js

module.exports =  (app) => {

  function hello_2018(){
    console.log('hello you');
  }

  hello_2018:hello_2018

};
```

a second class

```
var hello = require('./hello');
console.log(hello);
hello.hello_2018();
```

Comment: You're trying to assign an object key value pair inside a function for a start. You could return an object  `return {  hello_2018 }` in side that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the export function, you are writing key-value pair.

```
function hello_2018() {
    console.log('hello you');
}
module.exports = {
    hello_2018: hello_2018
};
// Second file
var hello = require('./hello');
console.log(hello);
hello.hello_2018();
```